# How to properly configure telegraf to write into InfluxDB data coming from MQTT

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I have an ESP8266 that sends MQTT data (float values) to my MQTT broker (mosquitto). I cannot get telegraf to write into the InfluxDB database. Do anyone have a sample configuration for telegraf? Using a python script I can successfully overcome telegraf but I prefer to use a maintained software, like telegraf, instead.

Another point, I also enabled telegraf with the default configuration that writes system info into influxDB, and it is working. However using grafana to plot the data, whenever I enable the "GROUP BY time ($interval)" into the query, no data points are returned. Seems like there is a problem in the data format.

Answer (score 0):

The string sent to MQTT must be formatted as follows to be parsed correctly by the default influxdb telegraf parser:
`seriesName,tag1=tagname1,tag2=tagname2 value1=123,value2=456`

for example using the client utils:

`mosquitto_pub -t smartmeter -m "energy,location=basement value=5"`
will write to the smartmeter topic (which needs to be subscribed in telegraf.conf). It will then write to the energy series, set a location tag and write the value 5.
Telegraf will also write default tags (mqtt topic and host) into the influxdb.

Regarding your second question: you have to use `$__interval` as a group by condition.